# How to download OpenStreetMap tiles from CloudMade?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, openstreetmap, cloudmade

how to download cloudmade map tiles? i have to download tiles with different zoom levels? how save these tiles to database for later loading? any sample code available? any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options available to you.

First, you can use the Javascript "Web Maps API". This is useful if you are wanting to show the maps on a website. It will download the required tiles and display them appropriately, and give you the interface to pan and zoom the map. See their pages at http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/web-maps-api

Second option is if you want to access the map tiles directly. They call it their HTTP Maps API. You will need to make the calcuations of which tiles to download, how to arrange them etc for your own application. Have a look at http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/tiles

Finally, although you don't mention it in your question, I see the question is tagged with "iphone" and other related things. Perhaps you want to look at their iPhone SDK, which is similar to the Web Maps API. See http://www.developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/iphone-sdk/Examples for examples on how to use it.

Comment: All links in answer seem dead.

Comment: CloudMade stopped their tiles service a while ago.